# Getting current execution date in a task or asset in dagster

Tags: python, dagster

Is there an easier way than what I'm doing to get the current date in an `dagster` asset, than what I'm currently doing?

```
def current_dt():
    return datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

@asset
def my_task(current_dt):
    return current_dt
```

In `airflow` these are passed by default in the python callable function definition ex: `def my_task(ds, **kwargs):`

Comment: if you're using the current date to do some kind of partitioned operation you might want to look into partitioned assets - https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/partitions-schedules-sensors/partitions

Comment: @zyd it's the scheduled execution date for a daily task that I need, just realized above won't allow me to backfill as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dagster, the typical way to do things that require Airflow `execution_date`s is with partitions:

```py
from dagster import asset, build_schedule_from_partitioned_job, define_asset_job, DailyPartitionsDefinition

partitions_def = DailyPartitionsDefinition(start_date="2020-01-01")

@asset(partitions_def=partitions_def)
def my_asset(context):
    current_dt = context.asset_partitions_time_window_for_output().start

my_job = define_asset_job("my_job", selection=[my_asset], partitions_def=partitions_def)

defs = Definitions(
    assets=[my_asset],
    schedules=[build_schedule_from_partitioned_job(my_job)],
)
```

This will set up a schedule to fill each daily partition at the end of each day, and you can also kick off runs for particular partitions or kick off backfills that materialize sets of partitions.